# angular dragdrop codef0rmer ng-repeat inserts empty object and removes elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using [angular dragdrop codef0rmer](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) library which gives cool features!

But however when I try to drag elements between two arrays (`ng-repeat`) I see many empty objects are created.

See this **[this](https://plnkr.co/edit/t3lbEyQgdPeaCDytYZdU?p=preview)** plnkr code. When you try to move elements around (within and across the green drop area) you can see empty objects are created in both of the arrays. This is problem 1.

> [image: empty objects created]

But I need way more dynamic (multiple `ng-repeat` within `ng-repeat`) like given in **[this](https://plnkr.co/edit/FQAGinXSImJ6YVrXqRBL?p=preview)** plunkr.
Now the problem gets more complicated when we drap and drop within and around other containers (yellow).

- it removes one element from each array.
- creates empty objects like above problem.

> [image: item gets deleted]

I have tried all the ways around but no luck! Any helps, suggestions appreciated.